# Whats a good strategy for localising WordPress post and page content?

Tags: multisite, localization, conditional-content

I'm aware of the various functions for localising elements of themes and plugins - `__(), x()` and the `textdomain` concept but how does one go about providing localised versions of actual post and page content?

I have a strategy in mind which would involve multisite with two domain mappings for .eu and .de (English and German respectively). I could then either provide the ubiquitous flag links in the header or use something a bit more sophisticated involving [geoIP](http://maxmind.github.io/GeoIP2-php/). Additionally, I would need to translate error messages and any hardcoded headings in templates.

However, this doesn't address the issue of localised *content*. Is there some way to mark a page or post as localised to a language?

Comment: There are multiple plugins to deal with that (see my profile for one). The details are probably too much for a single answer.

Comment: @toscho vielen Dank!